# How to find a .desktop file for a given gnome search icon

Tags: 20.04, gnome, icons, menu

Is there a generic way to find the `.desktop` entry for a specific menu entry in the gnome-search bar?

For example, I was trying to find the `.desktop` entry for the gnome *Settings* application.
As shown in this image:

[image]

---

Note that I already found this particular `.desktop` file because I knew that the official application name is `gnome-control-center`.
Thus the following command got me the right file:

```bsh
$ locate '*.desktop' | grep gnome-control-center
/usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop
```

However, this is not foolproof because the name of a desktop entry can be different from the application name.

So, I would love to learn a ***generic*** way of finding the `.desktop` entry for a given icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this by using the following command:

```
grep -r "Name.*=Settings" --include="*.desktop" --exclude-dir=boot,dev,proc,run,snap,sys / 2> /dev/null
```

where:

- `grep -r "Name.*=Settings"` - recursively finds needed line with displayed *Settings* word on icon;
- `--include="*.desktop"` - instructs grep to search only inside desktop-files;
- `--exclude-dir=boot,dev,proc,run,snap,sys` - excludes directories from search;
- `/` - means to start search in the top directory;
- `2> /dev/null` - sends all errors to `/dev/null` to hide them.

Comment: Awesome, I'll mark it as accepted.       
It is good to add that this works well because `Name` is a required field in the desktop-entry specification https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/